# PHP-FPM requires restart to access generated file when visiting webpage

Tags: php, apache, php-7

As part of a web-based project I work on, we generate new "sites" which are accessed by passing in a different parameter to `$_GET`. All of the sites live in `/usr/local/sites`. None of the sites are owned (either user or group) by the user we use (`hwphp`, `www-data` is the default apache user still), but the user is in the group so can read all files in the directories.

I have a python script that generates sites and after running it, half the time when I try and visit it by going to `http://localhost/index.php?site=newsite` I get `File not found: /var/local/sites/newsite/config/config.ini` though running PHP CLI it can find the file and `hwphp` user can read it just fine, just when I go through PHP-FPM/Apache it fails.

Here's my pool configuration:

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
; the variable $pool can be used in any directive and will be replaced by the
; pool name ('www' here)
[submitty]

user = hwphp
group = hwphp

listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm-submitty.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
;listen.mode = 0660

pm = dynamic

pm.max_children = 5

pm.start_servers = 2

pm.min_spare_servers = 1

pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

and my apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.56.101:80>
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    ServerAdmin ADMIN@DOMAIN.HERE
    ServerName 192.168.56.101

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/submitty/site/public
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm index.cgi

    SuexecUserGroup hwphp hwphp

    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        AddHandler php7-fcgi .php
        Action php7-fcgi /php7-fcgi
        Alias /php7-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi
        FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm-submitty.sock -pass-header Authorization

        <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
            SetHandler php7-fcgi
        </FilesMatch>

        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>

    <Files .*>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Files>

    <Files *~>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Files>

    <Files #*>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Files>

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/local/submitty/site/public>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel error
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/submitty.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/submitty.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

as soon as I do:

```
service php7.0-fpm restart
```

and it works fine and the file is found. Not sure why this might be as it makes no sense (and why a simple restart is what fixes it).

Server is Ubuntu 16.04, using PHP 7 and Apache 2.4, everything from the stock apt-get installs.

Comment: When you say, "half the time" - do you mean this is intermittent? Or can you reproduce this at will by using a unique "newsite" name, which is resolved by restarting? Where exactly do you get the error? Can you show the code for the controller which processes the `$_GET['site']` parameter?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't always happen. However, it does seem to reliably happen when I go to a site that doesn't exist, get an error about it not existing, then create it, then try and go to that site, I get an error. The relevant PHP code that is catching is just an `if (!file_exists($ini_file))` block where `$ini_file = /var/local/sites/newsite/config/config.ini`. However, restart php7.0-fpm and everything works as expected. These errors also only started after switching from suPHP to PHP-FPM when going from 14.04 to 16.04.

Comment: I'm also confident about what user is getting run as I've put a `print(exec('whoami'));` at the top of `index.php` and it prints out `hwphp` which can access the aforementioned `config.ini` file (and using PHP CLI, `file_exists($ini_file)` returns true as expected.

Comment: Possibly a problem with a cache like ZendOpCache or APC?

Comment: Yup, it was a problem with opcache, which I wasn't expecting as it only talks about `*.php` files, but guess it caches anything that goes through `file_exists()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that PHP was doing some caching of the file read which was causing the issues when trying to open the files. Doing a restart of php-fpm flushed the cache and made things just work.